# Gitlab-ce docker container unaccessable over https

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am having an issue accessing local gitlab over https. 
I installed it on Ubuntu/Redhat 8 with the same results, port 443 is not reachable. 
Under /etc/gitlab/ssl/ I have created a self signed certificate and key

```
xxx.crt
xxx.key
```

Then configured it I followed the instruction giving here. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#manually-configuring-https.  the issue that I am having is that I am not able to connect to gitlab over https. http works just fine

Odd behavior:
per documentation By default, when you specify an external_url starting with ‘https’, NGINX will no longer listen for unencrypted HTTP traffic on port 80. but that's not the case even with external_url is set.

So I check /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf after I configured it and I saw the server port is still pointing to *:80. I changed it to 443 stop/start getlab container and it broke with unreachable.

To get it back working I revert the changes and I did the following:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo docker restart gitlab
```

Now it's back responding on port 80 and not 443.

Answer (score 2):

> http works just fine

HTTP should not work, see "[Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#redirect-http-requests-to-https)"

> By default, when you specify an `external_url` starting with 'https', NGINX will
>   no longer listen for unencrypted HTTP traffic on port 80.
>   If you want to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS you can use the `redirect_http_to_https` setting.

```
external_url "https://gitlab.example.com"
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
```

So double-check your `gitlab.rb`, then `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: @Moe Did you reconfigure Gitlab when you changed it to 443?

Comment: I have been at it for sometime and I think I have figured it out, still testing... if I modify the gitlab.rb file manually then run  gitlab-ctl reconfigure. this will overwrite the modification I made to the gitlab.rb hence it fails over https and it uses port 80.  but if I modify gitlab.rb and only stop/start gitlab that seems to activate the changes I made including the cert modification. I was able to do this with compose.yml  now I am trying it with just run command.

Comment: @Moe OK. Another approach: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1079#note_19892670

Comment: @Moe But your approach to restart gitlab is the one mentioned in https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#configure-gitlab.

Comment: I meant to say gitlab-ctl stop/start --> Here is what I did. I got a handle of the container shell by running sudo docker exec -it gitlab  /bin/bash now I am inside the container --> then instead of  gitlab-ctl reconfigure I ran gitlab-ctl stop/start. what it's referenced in the link is restarting the gitlab container itself.

Comment: @Moe OK. The approaches I mentioned above are for a more static permanent modification, instead of your runtime "exec bash" modification.

Comment: I wasn't able to get working with the mentioned method above.it doesn't work for me. if you have created it before can you share your full command of getting the container started?